# Tree with two roots

Tags: tikz-trees

I want to put the root certs, under ca root, (but not in the same tree).
Here is my mwe

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz} 
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
    \usetikzlibrary{chains}
    \usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,anchor=west]
    \tikzstyle{selected}=[dashed,fill=red!30]
    \tikzstyle{optional}=[dashed,fill=blue!50]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and
        two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},
           show background rectangle,
        background rectangle/.style={fill=gray!10},
        edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]
        \node {ca}
        child { node {root-ca}
            child { node {01.pem}}
            child { node {02.pem}}
            child { node {db}
            child { node {...}}}
            child [missing] {}
            child { node {private}
            child { node {root-ca.key}}}
        }
        child [missing] {}
        child [missing] {}
        child [missing] {}
        child [missing] {}
        child [missing] {}
        child [missing] {}
        child { node {root-ca.crt}}
        child { node {root-ca.csr}}
        child { node  {signing-ca}
            child { node [selected]{01.pem}}
            child { node{02.pem}}
        child { node {db}
        child { node {...}}}
        child [missing] {}
             child { node {private}
                child { node {signing-ca.key}}}
        }
        child [missing] {}    child [missing] {}    child [missing] {}    child [missing] {}  child [missing] {}
        child { node {root-ca.crt}}
        child { node {root-ca.csr}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and
        two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},
        show background rectangle,
        background rectangle/.style={fill=gray!10},
        edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]
        \node {certs}
            child { node {simple.org.crt}}
            child { node {simple.org.csr}}
            child { node [optional]{simple.org.key}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here the output[image]

Comment: I change my code to be compilable

Comment: Oh, you used two `tikzpicture`s to get that output. That makes more sense :-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't reproduce your output and don't know how `mycolor` is defined, but you can use the `positioning` library:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,backgrounds,positioning}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{every node/.style={draw=black,thick,anchor=west},
  selected/.style={dashed,fill=red!30},
  optional/.style={dashed,fill=gray!50},}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and
        two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},
           show background rectangle,
        background rectangle/.style={fill=gray!10},
        edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]
        \node (ca) {ca}
        child { node {root-ca}
            child { node {01.pem}}
            child { node {02.pem}}
            child { node {db}
            child { node {...}}}
            child [missing] {}
            child { node {private}
            child { node {root-ca.key}}}
        }
        child [missing] {}
        child [missing] {}
        child [missing] {}
        child [missing] {}
        child [missing] {}
        child [missing] {}
        child { node {root-ca.crt}}
        child { node {root-ca.csr}}
        child { node  {signing-ca}
            child { node [selected]{01.pem}}
            child { node{02.pem}}
        child { node {db}
        child { node {...}}}
        child [missing] {}
             child { node {private}
                child { node {signing-ca.key}}}
        }
        child [missing] {}    child [missing] {}    child [missing] {}    child [missing] {}  child [missing] {}
        child { node {root-ca.crt}}
        child { node {root-ca.csr}};

        \node [below=of ca.center |- current bounding box.south] {certs}
            child { node {simple.org.crt}}
            child { node {simple.org.csr}}
            child { node [optional]{simple.org.key}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tree below tree]